# how to store in array and display them

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <h1>Lab 4 Exercise 2</h1>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="recordform">
    <p><i>Please complete your registration</i></p>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Person Register</legend>
      <label for="icno">IC No </label>
      <input type="text" id="icno" size="20" placeholder="E.g810312102121">

      <label for="name">Name </label>
      <input type="text" id="name" size="45"><br/>

      <button type="button" id="submit">Add Record</button>
      <button type="button" id="display">Display Records</button><br/>
    </fieldset>
  </form>

  <script>
    var inputArray = [];
    var input1 = document.getElementById("icno");
    var input2 = document.getElementById("name");
    document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", myfunction);

    function myfunction() {
      inputArray.push(input1.value);
      inputArray.push(input2.value);
      alert("Thanks for submitting");
    }

    document.getElementById("display").onclick;

    function function2() {
      alert("These are the list of records");
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I'm trying to store the input values into an array when user clicks <kbd>Add Record</kbd> button.

And would like to fetch and display the record using an alert message when user clicks <kbd>Display Records</kbd> button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution.

1. Get the value of input elements into `input1` and `input2`  when user clicks <kbd>Add Record</kbd>.
2. Display the values from `inputArray` using index. Check this link for more info - https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <h1>Lab 4 Exercise 2</h1>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="recordform">
    <p><i>Please complete your registration</i></p>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Person Register</legend>
      <label for="icno">IC No </label>
      <input type="text" id="icno" size="20" placeholder="E.g810312102121">

      <label for="name">Name </label>
      <input type="text" id="name" size="45"><br/>

      <button type="button" id="submit">Add Record</button>
      <button type="button" id="display">Display Records</button><br/>
    </fieldset>
  </form>

  <script>
    var inputArray = [],
      input1,
      input2;
    document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", myfunction);
    document.getElementById("display").addEventListener("click", displayrecords);

    function myfunction() {
      input1 = document.getElementById("icno").value;
      input2 = document.getElementById("name").value;
      inputArray.push(input1, input2);
      alert("Thanks for submitting");
    }

    function displayrecords() {
      alert("Input 1: " + inputArray[0] + "\nInput 2: " + inputArray[1]);
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: what if i want to add another record and then display all the records?

Comment: Use a loop and multi-dimensional array.